# Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, migration

I'm having som test databases running Oracle 10 & 11 that I plan to try to migrate to PostgreSQL.

Some googling hinted that the perl script "ora2pg" could be of use, and free of charge. However, now I've spent too much time trying to get that running on my winx64 machine, since MinGw won't compile it and activeperl modules hates me.

Are there any other worthy, free, tools to take a look at or should I get a Linuxbox up & running and try ora2pg that way?

Regards

Comment: You could ask EnterpriseDB when using one of their products, you pay for support anyway.

Comment: Well, no, I use postgresql, not EnterpriseDB. If it will work though, I might consider it in an upcoming case

Comment: Oracle -> PostgreSQL != Oracle -> EnterpriseDB.  EnterpriseDB offers a suite of Oracle emulation features not present in Vanilla PostgreSQL.  You might also look at Fyracle, which is a version of Firebird with Oracle emulation functionality.

Comment: I changed the subject and the question to reflect the comment about using PostgreSQL and not the "Advanced Server" from EnterpriseDB

Comment: Additionally, VirtualBox + Linux distro of your choice = perhaps a solution for you to run this script?

Comment: Ah, thanks, and sorry for the mismatch PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB. If the project will get OK it will probably be enterpriseDB but since I'm not speaking Postgres fluently at all I start with it as a testbench.
Guess VirtualBox and CentOs will be my way with ora2pg. Thanks for commenting

Comment: Not sure about cost, but EnterpriseDB have a migration tool [for vanilla postgres too](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products-overview/postgres-plus-solution-pack/migration-toolkit) - perhaps what @Frank was referring to?

Comment: Thanks Jack, i didnt know of that tool, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

We also found existing tools tricky to work with, so ended up hacking together a solution using the sqlalchemy library in python. Our general approach was to mirror the source database; hackily convert data types where necessary; create the target database; copy across the data in chunks.

For an example, see: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/oracle2postgres/blob/master/migration.ipynb. Using this approach, we migrated a fairly large database (~100 schema, with >1000 tables, some tables with >200 million rows) from Oracle to Postgres.

For more detail, see: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/oracle2postgres. The package can be installed with `pip install oracle2postgres`. If you hit problems when reusing the code, feel free to raise an issue and we'll do our best to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make ora2pg work.  It's best tool for this, possibly the only one.  Also, if you can't get that to work, you will probably have problems using many other possible tools for PostgreSQL.  Try to get help sorting these issues out, and you will be able to use the right tools.

Comment: haven't made it work yet. I'm not a perl guy unfortunately. I installed the environment on two different linux machines and one windows and it won't work on any of them. Ora2pg says that there are no oracle driver, and cpan says it's installed..so no luck there.

Comment: Did you get it to work in the end? I managed to install ora2pg in Debian 7 but when I run it, the output.sql that I get is almost empty. I don't get any errors though...